# Object not Found after installing Wordpress w/ XAMPP

Tags: wordpress, object, xampp

I just finished installing Wordpress (through Bitnami) and am running an Apache server with XAMPP. After installation, it tried to load the initial blog page and had the error. I can access localhost, but not the http://localhost/wordpress. No other questions about this topic seem to have this same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Create a  new folder (site)
- From the link below, download and extract the WordPress loader (installer) php script into the new folder:

  http://www.alistercameron.com/2010/04/09/wordpress-loader-faster-easier/
- Run `http://localhost/<new_folder>/wordpress_loader.php` and follow the on-screen instructions to complete the installation

Comment: I tried loading the .php file, but it still says file not found. Should the folder be under XAMPP/htdocs?